# Can an atomic structure created after a simulation performed at 251K in LAMMPS be initialized directly to 268K in a separate simulation?

Tags: molecular-dynamics, molecular-modeling, lammps, nucleation

I have a combined mW water and FCC111 Aluminium substrate model to study ice nucleation and adhesion. This simulation is performed at 251K which is the temperature for the actual real-world experiment. At the end of this simulation, I write a data file for the end structure.

My question is that - can this end structure/data file obtained from the previous simulation be reused in a separate simulation where I simply initialise it at 268K directly in NVT ensemble? Or should I initialise the structure at 251K and slowly raise the temperature to 268K before performing other operations (application of tensile force etc.)

Any help or insight on this is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, could you mention what "mW water" is exactly? Thanks, and *Welcome to Stack Exchange!*

Comment: @uhoh hadn't heard of this either, but it seems to be [a type of water model](http://www.sklogwiki.org/SklogWiki/index.php/MW_model_of_water)

Comment: The answer could be mostly yes but sometimes no. because there are so many other parameters at play. The best thing would be to perform different simulations, one directly using the structure at 251K, another by raising the temperature from 251K to 268K, and compare the results.